# How to validate the file name in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a form with  three input fields. I want to validate the input value before processing them. Where I want to validate the file name before processing it. I use regular expression and alpha_dash. But I got an error for a valid file name. I want my file name only to contain small letter, numbers, underscore and dashes. How can I check the validation of the file name for my file?

**Html**

```
 <form action="create" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {{csrf_field()}}
      <table cellpadding="2" width="20%"  align="center"
         cellspacing="2">

         <tr>
           <td colspan=2>
           <center><font size=4><b>Add the iteams  please</b></font></center>
           </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td>Heading</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="heading" id="heading" size="30">
           {!! $errors->first('heading', '<p class="red">:message</p>') !!}
           </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td>Image</td>
           <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="40">
           {!! $errors->first('image', '<p class="red">:message</p>') !!}
           </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Item" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
```

**controller part**

1. Using Regular expression format:

**- I got error message, “ The image format is invalid” .**

```
 public function store(){
    $this->validate(request(),[
          'heading'=>'required',
          'contentbody'=>'required',
           ‘image'=>['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048','regex:/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/' ]

        ]);

}
```

2. using Alpa_dash:

**- I got error message, “The image may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes” .**

```
public function store(){
 $this->validate(request(),[
           'heading'=>'required',
          'contentbody'=>'required',
          'image'=>'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|alpha_dash'
}
```

Please help, 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else has the same problem like me. I solved my problem by changing the filename to the current time-stamp instead of using the original filename. That way, I don't need to be worried about the validation of the original filename to be saved in the database.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
          'heading'=>'required',
          'contentbody'=>'required',
          'image'=>['required','image','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg','max:2048']

        ]);

         if($request->hasFile('image')){

            $inputimagename= time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->storeAs('public/upload', $inputimagename);

          Post::create([
             'heading'=>request('heading'),
             'content'=>request('contentbody'),
               'image'=>$inputimagename,

            ]);


         }

       return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Create custom validation rule class, for example `Filename`, and put it at the path `app/Rules/Filename.php`.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Filename implements Rule
{
    protected $regex;

    public function __construct(string $regex)
    {
        $this->regex = $regex;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (!($value instanceof UploadedFile) || !$value->isValid()) {
            return false;
        }

        return preg_match($this->regex, $value->getClientOriginalName()) > 0;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute name is invalid.';
    }
}
```

2. In your request rules add this custom rule like this:

```php
use App\Rules\Filename;

public function store() {
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'heading' => 'required',
        'contentbody' => 'required',
        'image' => [
            'required',
            'image',
            'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
            'max:2048',
            new Filename('/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/'), // This is your custom rule
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom regex I reckon

```
^[a-z0-9_.-]*$
```

and in your validation use like this

```
public function store(){
    $this->validate(request(),[
          'heading'=>'required',
          'contentbody'=>'required',
           ‘image'=>'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|regex:/^[a-z0-9_.-]*$/'

        ]);
```

**Edit 2:**

I am not sure but as per docs laravel supports only the mentioned format. however I found no issue with jpg when I used validation for images but still lets this out too..

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules)

**EDIT 3**

for custom validation see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pyramid. But I still get the same error, "The image format is invalid" .

Comment: Okay @   Mr. Pyramid

Comment: check the answer again as per doc you may facing this problem because of jpg

Comment: Thank you. But I got the same error. Is it possible to do custom validation  for it ?  I don't know how to do customer validation in Laravel .

Comment: yeah you can check the reference I have put in my answer

Comment: I tried to use custom validation. But I couldn't pass the original file name as it is. The file name is changed to a different name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155332/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-user7428112).