# How to validate input file name in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I want to validate image name in laravel. How can I get the value of input image name and pass it to `rules()` method in custom created `UploadRequest`. I want to validate if image name is maximum 20 characters and only alpha numeric.

uploadRequest file:
[image: uploadRequest file]

upload form view:
[image: upload form view]

Answer (score 0):

Someone already ask the question you should tcheck it. And for the information a custom validation is recommended.

[Question already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419738/how-to-validate-the-file-name-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont want to validate if image name is unique, just if it is longer than 20 characters. I want to validate name length in rules() method.

Comment: I point you to this answer because they used the regex to solve the problm

Comment: I have found easy solution. If statement in controller method that checks length of  file name in request resolves the problem.